# Login with CURL and x-auth

Tags: curl, php-curl, bearer-token

**Need to do a CURL request to a site that requires login first**

I'm unable to actually login, presumably because I'm not able to provide the X-AUTH token. I must be missing something but my understanding of the flow as per below (what occurs when I review network requests):

1. Go to login page and obtain cookies `https://nycidling.azurewebsites.net/login`
2. Do pre-flight OPTIONS request `https://idlingapi.azurewebsites.net/api/users/login`
3. Login with POST request `https://idlingapi.azurewebsites.net/api/users/login`

The last step seems to require an X-AUTH token, but the point of logging in is to obtain it.. so I must be missing something basic...

If I don't provide the X-Auth token as part of the request the server has a 500  error message `The given header was not found.`

If I provide the `X-Auth: token` I get `401 Unauthorized`response as per below

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate: X-Auth Access
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://nycidling.azurewebsites.net
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:0cd212c4-7265-421c-88c6-635f41af2791
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Request-Context
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 02 Apr 2022 12:40:41 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

**What am I missing?**

The intuitive part would be that you use the cookie from the GET request to provide as `Bearer token` during the POST request together with the username and password. But this does not seem to be the flow from the network tabs...

*In short, how do I provide an X-AUTH token already prior to having logged in?* What am I missing?

**CODE**

```
// Variables
$userAgent = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.83 Safari/537.36';
$cookie = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookies.txt';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password'; // Has special characters if that matters..

// Settings for all curl requests
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
));

// Get cookies from login site
$url = 'https://nycidling.azurewebsites.net/login';
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $userAgent,
    // CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
// curl_close($ch);

// Options method (login)
$url = 'https://idlingapi.azurewebsites.net/api/users/login';
$headers = array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,x-auth",
    "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Host: idlingapi.azurewebsites.net",
    "Origin: https://nycidling.azurewebsites.net",
    "Referer: https://nycidling.azurewebsites.net/",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site",
    "User-Agent: $userAgent",
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'OPTIONS',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
// dd($response);

// Login (with cookies from above)
$url = "https://idlingapi.azurewebsites.net/api/users/login"; 
$postFields['emailaddress1'] = urlencode($username);
$postFields['idc_password'] = urlencode($password);

$headers = array(
    "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "Authorization: Bearer",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Content-Length: 75",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Host: idlingapi.azurewebsites.net",
    "Origin: https://nycidling.azurewebsites.net",
    "Referer: https://nycidling.azurewebsites.net/",
    'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"',
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0",
    'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"',
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site",
    "User-Agent: $userAgent",
    "X-Auth: c384bc21-2165-44ee-9353-2593532e2bcc:nLYROABzicqak8GKklq4IlOf1hJbXGDZ6NxLLdedrHE=:9772d6a8-9fed-4e8e-fc3d-1db1766b5adc:1648866676" // <== Where does this X-AUTH token get generated? It is also the response when logged in.. So how can it be obtained prior to login?
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postFields,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
dd($response);
```

**COOKIE FILE SEEMS TO STORE CORRECTLY***

```
#HttpOnly_.idlingapi.azurewebsites.net  TRUE    /   TRUE    0   ARRAffinitySameSite 3769bc7afaf737a4a03d956ebdfc5742c39a3f6232952e26cf18xxxxxxxxxxxx
#HttpOnly_.idlingapi.azurewebsites.net  TRUE    /   TRUE    0   ARRAffinity 3769bc7afaf737a4a03d956ebdfc5742c39a3f6232952e26cf18xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Have reviewed multiple stackoverflow questions to try to figure out, but have not been successful so far**

1. [how to login this web site by php curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51570008/how-to-login-this-web-site-by-php-curl/51570669)
2. [Login to page with curl in php and then visit link "logged in"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685487/login-to-page-with-curl-in-php-and-then-visit-link-logged-in)
3. [Login to remote site with PHP cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008817/login-to-remote-site-with-php-curl)
4. [How to login in with Curl and SSL and cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307744/how-to-login-in-with-curl-and-ssl-and-cookies)
5. [send request with x-auth-token in header php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31117778/send-request-with-x-auth-token-in-header-php)